# XAML Desinger window too small

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015

[image]

I am trying to transition into windows app development. However, when i use vs 2015 the designer box is really small. When I drag anything from the toolbox to the designer window it doesn't show up. Everything shows when I run the build but not in the designer. I've been googling and looking through stack but i can't find the answer. Can someone tell me how to get the designer to work.

Comment: You need to set `d:DesignHeight` and `d:DesignWidth`

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I think I set it wrong. I put d:DesigntHeight="1080px" d:DesignWidth="1920px" but nothing has changed. I still can't see anything.

Comment: Remove the "px", just `d:DesignHeight="1080"` (which btw, you misspelled DesignHeight in that example you gave) ....oh, and swap your yankees hat for a KC Royals hat. :P

Comment: I removed the px and corrected the spelling. I think I'm putting the d:DesignHeight in the wrong place. Am I supposed to put it in the "Page" tag in the MainPage.xaml? Sorry, I'm realizing this is a super noob question.

Comment: Ya up by the mc:Ignorable and namespaces, no worries.

Comment: I got it thanks to both of you guys. I had to restart visual studio after I added this. I'm not sure why but after I put the tags in and restarted vs it worked. Maybe vs needed to be updated. Thank you again guys for your patience and assistance.

Comment: Spoke too soon still showing the same small box. @chrisw [link](http://imgur.com/a/y6XBX)

Comment: Hahaha ok man, I just noticed in your screenshot you have the view ratio set at 17% (Look in the bottom left corner of the designer window right above the "Design" tab) set that to at least 100% ;)

Comment: Oh and also, you don't generally even need to set the DesignHeight/DesignWidth properties, or at least I don't normally. The Design area should still fill with whatever child content is provided.

Comment: I tried every setting all the way up to 800% still no dice. The box gets bigger but can't see anything I drop in. I tried to move this to a chat but my reputation is too low. I assumed it was a matter of configuration so I reset all settings and tried a new app and nothing. @ChrisW.

Comment: Hmm, ya I'm thinking it has to be some little nuance detail somewhere we're missing since you're the only one sitting in front of it. Maybe something to do with those settings in the top left corner? I'm not sure at this point if the last suggestions didn't do it for ya.

Comment: @ChrisW. thanks for helping. anyone else with this problem heres the solution i found. I uninstalled vs 2015. This is a very tedious process. After I uninstalled I did a force uninstall. Then I downloaded  the visual studio "Total Uninstaller" from github and ran that several times. I then manually uninstalled everything related to visual studio. rebooted then ran the total uninstaller again. Then I cleaned the %temp% folder and program data folder and then reinstalled visual studio and now I'm up and running. Its a lot to go through but completely uninstalling visual studio is NOT easy.